# C# - How do generics with the new() constraint get machine code generated?

Tags: c#, generics, clr

```
public T Foo<T, U>(U thing) where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

When there is no `new()` constraint, I understand how it would work. The JIT Compiler sees T and if it's a reference type makes uses the object versions of the code, and specializes for each value type case.

**How does it work if you have a new T() in there? Where does it look for?**

Comment: The new() constraint means your type must have a default (parameterless) constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean, what does the IL look like, the compiler will compile in a call to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>`.

The type you pass as `T` must have a public parameterless constructor to satisfy the compiler.

You can test this in [Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGFAQ2TJlKMpBBgGEYBvbGbmfY2qjXIAVGMNQoAPMIB8ACgCUMAO4ALVACdUYmAC46DJgBoYEVMsVcenHrZhbkwDRFPmxinLYC+2L0AAA==):

```
public static T Test<T>() where T : class, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

becomes:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    !!T Test<class .ctor T> () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 6 (0x6)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: call !!0 [mscorlib]System.Activator::CreateInstance<!!T>()
    IL_0005: ret
} // end of method C::Test
```

Comment: Follow up question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553686/c-sharp-why-does-a-class-new-constraint-use-activator-createinstancet.